# Collate MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

Preciso fazer um auto complete que consome uma base de dados em mongodb. 
As palavras podem ser escritas com ou sem acento, maiúsculas ou minúsculas, ou seja, preciso definir um collate no mongo que me permita fazer uma busca que ignore a acentuação e o case sensitive.

O mongo tem esse módulo de configuração ? Caso não, existe alguma maneira de resolver isso com o driver do c# ?

```
var filterBuilder = Builders<UnidadeCurricular>.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Exists(a => a.DeletedAt, false) & filterBuilder.Where(a => a.Nome.StartsWith(nome));
```

Comment: Fui dar uma pesquisada, e achei uns caras dizendo que o melhor modo é você guardar o campo a ser pesquisado 2 vezes [Colunas], 1 vez NORMAL, e outra LIMPA e tudo MINUSCULO. é até melhor em termos de pesquisa e performance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458950/mongodb-and-c-case-insensitive-search

Comment: Então, já tinha visto essa forma de fazer. Resolve mas não me parece um jeito "certo" de fazer .. será que nao tem uma forma mais automatica de fazer ?

Answer (score 0):

Tem um operador de query [chamado `$text`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/).

Um exemplo de como fazer seria:

```
var comandoPesquisa = new CommandDocument
{
    { "text", typeof(UnidadeCurricular).Name },
    { "search", nome }
};

var commandResult = _database.RunCommandAs<TextSearchCommandResult<T>>(comandoPesquisa);
```

[Tirei daqui](http://www.manik-software.co.uk/blog/post/Text-search-in-MongoDB-using-C.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Para que seja encontrado na pesquisa tanto palavras com acentuação quanto sem acentos é necessário definir um indice de texto com os campos usados na busca pertencentes à collection.
Assim:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { SEUCAMPOSTRING: "text" } )
```

e depois para pesquisar definir a linguagem para português na busca.

```
db.collection..find({$text:{$search:"TEXTOPROCURADO",$language:'pt'}})
```

fontes:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/